# Java Split String Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split, tokenize

Here is a String, I want to split the string such that the symbols and "words" are separate. For example:

```
String s = "/xyz/abc[bcd(text(),\"string\")]";
```

I want to have a String array like

```
String[] result = {"/","xyz","/","abc","[","bcd","(","text","(",")",",","\"","string","\"",")","]"}
```

How can I do this by using regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
String str = "/xyz/abc[bcd(text(),\"string\")]";

String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G(?>\\w+|\\W))\\s*");
```

This gives:

```
["/", "xyz", "/", "abc", "[", "bcd", "(", "text", "(", ")", ",", """, "string", """, ")", "]"]
```

#### Explanation:

- Regex is using \G which matches from end of last matched position
- `(?>..)` is an atomic group (More details: http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)

Comment: Thank you! What if string has whitespace, I wanna omit this white space while splitting this string? for example `String s = "/xyz/abc[     bcd(text(),\"string\")]";`

Comment: @anubhava nice answer could you explain a bit about what you're trying to do here?

Comment: @CSnerd: Hmm so you're chancing the nature of the problem. I am adding my explanation first then I will check whether modified question can be solved this way.

Comment: @anubhava I find a way I can use s = s.replaceAll(" ", ""); If modification of answer needs so much work. it is fine.

Comment: Glad to know. Also see updated code to discard spaced.

Answer (score 0):

User anubhava has answered your question, but in the future http://regexpal.com/ is very helpful when regexing. I use it all the time as a tool, though there are many options.

Helps with trial and error :)

Good luck, happy coding